# Avoid recreation of Kubernetes cluster when upgrading web api

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, kubernetes-service

Maybe I am missing something but am I right in thinking that if I want to update a webapi that is hosted in my kubernetes cluster in Azure I have to delete and recreate it?

The instructions I am seeing online seem to show deleting the cluster rather than upgrading the api

Paul

Comment: What you mean by `update a webapi that is hosted in my kubernetes cluster`? Your web API application? If yes then I would say it's only image update and then you would have to recreate your pods, either with recreating them(delete and recreate it) or for example you can use [Rolling Update](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/), you don't need to delete the whole cluster.

Comment: ok yes thats what I wanted - a situation where I dont have to delete the cluster, the guides I have seen are more about setting up from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's your web API application then it's only deployment image update, you don't need to delete the whole cluster.

---

There is an example of [updating a nginx deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment) with new image:

```
kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.16.1 --record
```

This way it will first create a new pods with newer version of image and once successfully deployed it will terminate old pods.

You can check status of the update by running

```
kubectl rollout status deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment
```

---

Additional resources:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#updating-resources
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/
- https://www.bluematador.com/blog/kubernetes-deployments-rolling-update-configuration